# Performance swapping integers vs double

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

For some reason my code is able to perform swaps on doubles faster than on the integers. I have no idea why this would be happening.

On my machine the double swap loop completes 11 times faster than the integer swap loop. What property of doubles/integers make them perform this way?

**Test setup**

- Visual Studio 2012 x64
- cpu core i7 950
- **Build as Release and run exe directly, VS Debug hooks skew things**

**Output:**

`Process time for ints 1.438 secs`

`Process time for doubles  0.125 secs`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

#define N 2000000000

void swap_i(int *x, int *y) {
    int tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}

void swap_d(double *x, double *y) {
    double tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}

int main () {
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    double d = 1.0, e = 2.0, iTime, dTime;
    clock_t c0, c1;

    // Time int swaps
    c0 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        swap_i(&a, &b);
    }
    c1 = clock();
    iTime = (double)(c1-c0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    // Time double swaps
    c0 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        swap_d(&d, &e);
    }
    c1 = clock();
    dTime = (double)(c1-c0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "Process time for ints " << iTime << " secs" << endl;
    cout << "Process time for doubles  " << dTime << " secs" << endl;
}
```

It seems that VS only optimized one of the loops as Blastfurnace explained.

When I disable all compiler optimizations and have my swap code inline inside the loops, I got the following results (I also switched my timer to std::chrono::high_resolution_clock):

`Process time for ints 1449 ms`

`Process time for doubles  1248 ms`

Comment: What is the output? I'm curious. Also, 32-bit machine or 64-bit machine? 32-bit or 64-bit code? Compiler? OS?

Comment: How many seconds are we talking for each here?

Comment: What *is* your machine?  I ran your program with a few different optimizations here, and I didn't get anything like you're seeing.  Cache behaviour maybe?

Comment: Interesting on a machine I have they are the same pretty much `Process time for ints 6.39 secs`
 `Process time for doubles  6.4 secs`

Comment: Another thought - are you using CUDA or something like that?

Comment: @Timo Geusch: I'm getting this too. 0.662 sec for ints, 0.036 sec for doubles.

Comment: On my machine (Visual Studio, 64-bit machine): Process time for ints 29.34 secs, Process time for doubles  29.479 secs

Comment: I had those numbers in Debug, but in release I got a similar discrepancy to what OP is asking about.

Comment: Well, your benchmark is probably lying. `clock` is the worse way of measuring wall time, and I bet you have CPU energy saving when it clocks at a lot lower speeds unless you put some load for ~ few seconds. I bet if you swap double and int test order, then double will be slower.

Comment: @VladLazarenko clock() is not processor speed dependent.

Comment: @Vlad I already tried changing the order of the tests and double is still faster. Process time for ints 1.438 secs
Process time for doubles  0.125 secs

Comment: BTW, gcc is optimizing all swaps out. So the test is covering thin air.

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave: Right. It is a silly approximation.. no good for anything :(

Comment: I'm curious as to whether the results are consistent with `std::swap`.

Comment: @oldrinb Just tested with std::swap and results are the same. The issue was VS optimization only optimized the double swap loop for some reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the answer by looking at the generated assembly.

Using Visual C++ 2012 (32-bit Release build) the body of `swap_i` is three `mov` instructions but the body of `swap_d` is completely optimized away to an empty loop. The compiler is smart enough to see that an even number of swaps has no visible effect. I don't know why it doesn't do the same with the `int` loop.

Just changing `#define N 2000000000` to `#define N 2000000001` and rebuilding causes the `swap_d` body to perform actual work. The final times are close on my machine with `swap_d` being about 3% slower.